# messages delayed from cloud functions to flutter

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I create message document from api to firestore.
I create a new message to phoneNumber's `subscriber/{phoneNumber}/sites/{sitesId}/messages` collection.
Then my app display snackbar when create a new message document.

But sometimes it comes too late, sometimes it comes right away.

I checked to `messages` document. the new document is created immediately in `messages` collection when i create a new document from api. i dont understand, why cloud function always dont display snackbar immediately?

my index.js

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
const db = admin.firestore();


exports.sendNotGetNewMessage = functions.firestore
    .document("subscribers/{subscriberId}/sites/{sitesId}/messages/{messageId}")
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
      const newMessage = snap.data();
      const {subscriberId} = context.params;
      const subscriber = await db.collection("subscribers")
          .doc(subscriberId).get();
      const fcmToken = subscriber.get("fcmToken");
      const payload = {
        notification: {
          title: "a new notification",
          body: " " + newMessage.message,
          sound: "beep",
          channel_id: "TextFirebase",
          android_channel_id: "TextFirebase",
          priority: "high",
        },
      };
      try {
        const response = await admin.messaging()
            .sendToDevice(fcmToken, payload);
        console.log(response);
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But sometimes it comes too late, sometimes it comes right away.

This behaviour is typical of an incorrect life cycle management of your Cloud Function.

As explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions), to correctly manage the life cycle of your background triggered Cloud Function you MUST return a Promise or a value, in order to indicate to the CF platform that the CF has completed, and to avoid the CF is terminated before all the asynchronous operations are done.

Concretely, in your case it happens sometimes that your Cloud Function is terminated before the asynchronous operations are completed, because you don't return a Promise or a value at the end of your code. The other times, the Cloud Function platform does not terminate the Function immediately and the asynchronous operations can be completed.

```js
exports.sendNotGetNewMessage = functions.firestore
    .document("subscribers/{subscriberId}/sites/{sitesId}/messages/{messageId}")
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {

        try {
            const newMessage = snap.data();
            const { subscriberId } = context.params;

            const subscriber = await db.collection("subscribers")
                .doc(subscriberId).get();
            const fcmToken = subscriber.get("fcmToken");
            const payload = {
                notification: {
                    title: "a new notification",
                    body: " " + newMessage.message,
                    sound: "beep",
                    channel_id: "TextFirebase",
                    android_channel_id: "TextFirebase",
                    priority: "high",
                },
            };
            const response = await admin.messaging().sendToDevice(fcmToken, payload);
            console.log(response);
            return true; // <= See here
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
            return true; // <= See here
        }
    });
```

Note that if you don't need to log the `response`, you can just return the Promise returned by the `sendToDevice()` method, as follows:

```js
            const fcmToken = subscriber.get("fcmToken");
            const payload = {
                notification: {...},
            };
            return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(fcmToken, payload);
```